# “TeX Live Manager” not work (windows 10 - 64bit & texlive 2015)

Tags: texlive

I have just installed TeX Live 2015 using "install-tl-WINDOWS.bat"on windows 10-64bits.

When I click in "TeX Live Manager",nothing happens.

if I execute "tlmgr-gui" in a command line, nothing happens & no message appear.

if I execute "tlmgr -gui" or "tlmgr --gui" in a command line,I got this:

The locale codeset (cp720) isn't one that perl can decode, stopped at C:\texlive\2015\tlpkg\tlperl\lib/Encode/Locale.pm line 123.
Compilation failed in require at C:\texlive\2015\tlpkg\tlperl\lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm line 1001..

what is the mistake?